# Changing Polygon shape on Zoom in and Zoom out in google maps using javascript

Tags: polygon, google-maps

In my application iam using google maps v3, on page load with default zoom level of 15 i load few polygons by passing points(latlng coordinates) from database on the google map now my question is when i zoom out the map the polygons shape has to be changed and size of the polygons has to be reduced how can i do this using javascript.